# I'm in the current development version after doing "do-release-upgrade -d", why?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I don't know how, but I was upgrading from ubuntu 11.10 using:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Then after the upgrade and a reboot, I did:

```
sudo lsb_release -a
```

and got:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: 
Ubuntu Description:Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

How was this possible? Is it possible to downgrade without a rebuild? I guess I'm an alpha tester for 14.04 now?

Comment: from the man-page of do-release-upgrade: `-d, --devel-release` 
`Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible` so it exactly that and upgraded to the latest development release.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic states questions about unreleased versions are off-topic. Bug reports about 14.04 may be filed at http://launchpad.net

Comment: Ah i see, doh. Bit stupid on my part. Checking if devel is available also means install it without a prompt.

Comment: This is why you should always use the written-out command line options like `--devel-release` in documentation, not the cryptic abbreviations like `-d`.  I did the same thing.  :(

Answer (score 3):

You have chosen to upgrade to the development version by choosing option -d in `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

So, for one reason or another, you've upgraded Ubuntu to a new version. Now, you're not liking the new version (or it's a development version and too unstable for your taste).

there are mainly two methods to downgrade and since its too long to state here so please check the community help page for that by clicking [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto).

Answer (score 0):

The release team is enabling upgrade paths that will allow jumping between releases. I don't really know why were you using `-d` parameter that will leave you in the latest development version, but that's expected... I guess. I've never seen someone jumping through  7 releases, ever, but with the recent changes in the upgrade paths I should be expecting some weird cases.

There's no method to downgrade Ubuntu version, just reinstall using your prefered LTS or normal releases after doing the mandatory backups.